# Firefox home page title Issue

Tags: html, firefox

how to change this

```
<title> Start Page</title>
```

to

```
 <title>&abouthome.pageTitle;</title>
```

Comment: Is there any problem in manually editing the source?

Comment: I think you need to give more context, is there anything other than Firefox and some html?

Answer (score 2):

Open up the file in your IDE, locate the `title` tag and modify its text node.